# Why does error appear when I try to iterate array of objects in my react.js component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Code example:

```
class Stepper extends Component {
    state ={
        quiz_data: [
            patient_data: [
                {name: "A", age: "1"},
                {name: "B", age: "2"},
                {name: "C", age: "3"},
                {name: "D", age: "4"},
            ]
        ]
    }

    render() {
        const {patient_data} = this.state.quiz_data
        console.log("patient_data: ", patient_data) // patient_data: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
        ...
    }

}
```

So, the log is: *patient_data: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]*

But if I try to iterate:

```
...

    render() {
        const {patient_data} = this.state.quiz_data
        console.log("patient_data: ", patient_data) // patient_data: undefined
        const options = patient_data.map((item) => 
                <option>Name: {item.name}, Age: {item.age}</option>
            )
    }

...
```

As you can see the log is: *patient_data: undefined*

And the error *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"* appears

Any idea?

Comment: Your first code block has an invalid literal as `state` and should throw a compiling error. It should be `quiz_data: { ... }` not `quiz_data: [...]`

Answer (score 0):

`quiz_data` is an array, if you want to destructure it as an object, you should define it like so:

```
state ={
    quiz_data: {
        patient_data: [
            {name: "A", age: "1"},
            {name: "B", age: "2"},
            {name: "C", age: "3"},
            {name: "D", age: "4"},
        ]
    }
}
```